# How to use Unicode characters as variable names without extraneous variant selector glyphs?

Tags: xcode, swift, unicode, emoji

When I test using emoji as variable names in Swift (XCode 7.2), I have major problems in that only some emoji work.  I've determined that it is because some emoji include their base Unicode codepoint followed by a "variation selector".

Is there a way to insert characters into my source code without the unprintable variation selector coming along with the ride and ruining my code?

This mostly seems to be the fault of Apple's implementation of Unicode, where using the character selection pane to insert ♣️ inserts the codepoint for Clubs followed by the variation selector for "use the emoji version, not the plain text style".  Inserting ♣ injects both the Clubs codepoint and the "use the text-style" selector.

If not, is there a list of characters to avoid using in variable names?  So far, I've found anything involving a card suit to be problematic, as well as any human-like emoji that Apple has enabled for skin tone selection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can input individual code points using the "Unicode Hex Input" input source that comes with Mac OS X. See [this guide](http://www.poynton.com/notes/misc/mac-unicode-hex-input.html) for enabling and using it.

In general, you probably want to *avoid non-ASCII identifiers* for exactly the reasons you mention. There are *many* other examples where non-ASCII identifiers can cause problems, and they offer almost no practical benefit.

Comment: Apple really should not have picked emoji as their primary example for using almost any Unicode character as a variable name if their own emoji implementation doesn't play nice with being used as an identifier. Luckily for me, I'm a native English speaker, so I don't need non-ASCII characters to have variable names that are meaningful in my native tongue.